# WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager fails to start cannot bind to address at port 10500

Tags: amazon-ec2, wso2

I am attempting to install and run the WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager on an Amazon EC2 Linux instance.  I carefully followed the install and deployment instructions at https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM101/Getting+Started.  I opened port 10500 in the EC2 console for my instance.  When I run the start script ./wso2server.sh in EMM_HOME/bin I get the following exception:

```
    `ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent} -  Error in initializing thrift transport
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not bind to port 10500
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createServer(TSSLTransportFactory.java:117)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getServerSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent.startThriftEntitlementService(EntitlementServiceComponent.java:328)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent.startThriftServices(EntitlementServiceComponent.java:299)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent.activate(EntitlementServiceComponent.java:161)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication.internal.ThriftAuthenticationServiceComponent.activate(ThriftAuthenticationServiceComponent.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket.<init>(SSLServerSocket.java:181)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.<init>(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:134)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:91)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createServer(TSSLTransportFactory.java:109)
... 62 more
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent} -  Failed  to initialize Entitlement Service
java.lang.Exception: Error in initializing thrift transport
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent.startThriftEntitlementService(EntitlementServiceComponent.java:355)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent.startThriftServices(EntitlementServiceComponent.java:299)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.internal.EntitlementServiceComponent.activate(EntitlementServiceComponent.java:161)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication.internal.ThriftAuthenticationServiceComponent.activate(ThriftAuthenticationServiceComponent.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)`
```

Thanks for any help, advice, or referral in advance.

Comment: <home>/repository/conf/carbon.xml change hostname element with your IP address

Answer (score 4):

Please try to change the HostName parameter in `carbon.xml` file which can be found at `/repository/conf` directory.  This must be equal to IP address of the instance this is running your WSO2 server.

`<HostName>localhost</HostName>`

`<MgtHostName>localhost</MgtHostName>`

This error happens when starting the thrift server that is used for XACML. If WSO2 EMM is not using that,  just for now,  you can disable the thrift server using using `identity.xml` file which can be found at `/repository/conf` directory.

`<EnableThriftService>true</EnableThriftService>`

Comment: Thank  you for pointing out that HostName must be updated.  It turns out that the MgtHostName parameter must also be updated for AWS EC2 installations to work.